# Why does the await inside the child call actually wait?

Tags: c#, async-await

Output for the below code is

```
A
B
C
```

Since the root call `FirstCall()` doesn't await, I would have expected the `Task.Delay` to not actually wait since the Task that is returned by the `ChildCall` bubbles up and is never waited.

Can someone explain why `Task.Delay` actually awaits when the root caller is not awaited?

Specifically, when `FirstCall` reaches the await statement inside it (`await ChildCall()`) the execution of the method is suspended and control returns to the Main method. Here FirstCall is not awaited - what is preventing it from then going ahead and executing `Console.ReadLine()`

```
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FirstCall();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        private static async Task FirstCall()
        {
            await ChildCall();
            Console.WriteLine("C");
        }

        private static async Task ChildCall()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");


            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
```

Comment: blocking and awaiting are 2 completely different terminologies usually used to describe different things. However, await, does actually await, which is what you see in your results. At this point i would keep researching the async and await pattern. these questions get asked every day, and there are literally boat loads of blogs and duplicates that can steer you in the right direction. This is your mission if you choose to accept it

Comment: I understand the difference between awaiting and blocking. I have updated the title. But I think the question is clear - why does ChildCall wait for Task.Delay to execute since the root call is not awaited.

Comment: That doesn't change anything at all. Similar to what @TheGeneral said. Load of duplicates and resources online on the subject.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari do point me to one that explains this and I will be happy to close this question.

Comment: Downvotes? Seriously? While at the same time no one here can point me to any definitive source. My team was right - SO really has changed in the last few years.

Comment: The thing is, you are waiting. The `Console.ReadLine` call waits till you press <Enter> on the console. If that didn't wait, you'd likely just see `A` output

Comment: Yes, the code is waiting on the ReadLine but the FirstCall() method completes before its child methods are done. I should have added another log before the ReadLine() to make that clear.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't `await`, you only continue the thread you are in.

If you write:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FirstCall();
        Console.WriteLine("D");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Your output will look something like:

```
D
A
B
C
```

or

```
A
D
B
C
```

Skipping await doesn't disable the other awaits. When calling an `async` task, you can think of it as creating a new Thread that does it's own thing. When you call `await` you are simply saying to the current thread, don't do anything until that one is done.

But the second thread can still call await a third thread, and tell itself to `await` or wait until the third thread is done. The first thread, if not awaited will just continue and close the program before the other threads finish.

You can test this by removing the `Console.Readline()` and instead write out `Main Thread Completed`

---

### EDIT: ADDITIONAL

To your specific Quesiton:

> Specifically, when FirstCall reaches the await statement inside it (await ChildCall()) the execution of the method is suspended and control returns to the Main method. Here FirstCall is not awaited - what is preventing it from then going ahead and executing Console.ReadLine()

The execution of the method is ***NOT*** suspended as you thought. See the example below of your edited code:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FirstCall();
        Console.WriteLine("Main Thread Finished...");
        var word = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Printed: " + word);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

In the image below, the left hand side I immediately Typed `test`. On the right hand side I waited for the child threads to complete:

[image]

So to answer your other question:

> So you are saying each child method has its own state machine that is honoured irrespective of what its parent is doing?

Partially...

To answer correctly you need to know the difference between a Task and a Thread.

### Task vs Thread

In short a `Task` uses a Thread Pool and a `Thread` uses a dedicated Thread. Think of a dedicated Thread as starting a secondary `Main(args)` function. Where as a Thread pool uses a parent-child-treelike structure (Could be wrong on this) to keep track of what threads are executing.

### What this means practically

- Both Tasks and Threads have complete internal states that is honoured irrespective of what its parent | EXCEPT When the Parent of a Task is completed, all the Children Tasks Stop **Immediately*.
- Tasks have **Return Types** where as Threads don't.
- For a program to stop - you have to stop all threads but you only have to stop the parent Task to stop the program.

Comment: So you are saying each child method has its own state machine that is honoured irrespective of what its parent is doing? Do you have any material I can refer to?

Comment: Updated the question to make it cleared on why I am asking this.

Comment: @bobbyalex Updated Answer to add more info

Comment: In short a Task uses a Thread Pool and a Thread uses a dedicated Thread. - This statement is incorrect. The implementation of how the awaitable works is up to the method. For eg: an IO bound awaitable does not use a thread - thread pool or otherwise.

Comment: @mrmoon: A `ThreadPool` is a grouping of threads, not a thread thing. If you call `await Task.Run` or `Delegate.Invoke`, you are dispatching work to a thread in a thread pool. Tasks and threads are intertwined, but not that tightly. In the OP's question, there is only one threas